# How to do a page publication workflow using a template and content types

Tags: asp.net, orchardcms

Hi I'm new to Orchard and ASP.NET development and need help on creating a workflow in Orchard.

I have a content type and I want to publish pages based on data from this content type. I want to create a workflow that would publish a page when a new content of a certain content type is published. The page should use a template and somehow use data from the content type within it. Is this possible using the UI or does it need ASP.NET development if where to start?

The reason why I can't publish a page directly is because I want to use the same content type with multiple page templates and display the same content differently.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use workflow for that. From your description of the scenario, you shouldn't have multiple content items, but only one, displayed under different templates. That's a job for different display types, not for multiple content items. Take a look at how the core content controller is displaying content items, and reproduce its logic, with a different display type. Then create the routes you need to point to that new controller. That should be cleaner, as well as more stable.